# ELI5: How do I make these FFT-related lists act properly?

Tags: python, python-2.7, fft

I have been working on an FFT-assignment for the past couple of weeks. It is due thursday, and I thought it would be quite cool to pick up Python and program an FFT-calculator that transformed from time to frequency domain. Now, I have just started TODAY with learning Python, so please do bear with me.

Anyways, I have stumbled upon a problem

The frequency is given by
(k*sample rate)/N

where k is an integer ranging from 0 to N-1, and where N is the amount of samples.

What I want is to have a list, freq[n], like this:

```
freq[n] = k[n]*sample rate/N
```

I have tried the following, but with no success:

```
samplerate = 44100
N = 2048
k = range(0,N-1)

for n in range(0,N-1):
    freq = k[n]*samplerate/N

print freq[2]
```

with following error:
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

I owe you guys a thousand beers if you are willing to help me

Edit: It really warms my heart that you guys are so nice to newbies like me :) Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `freq` is being re-assigned each time through your `for` loop. Instead, make it a `list` of the values for corresponding `n`:

```
freq = [(k[n] * samplerate) / N for n in range(0, N)]
```

or, given that `k[n] == n`, simply

```
freq = [(n * samplerate) / N for n in range(0, N)]
```

Note that `range` in Python excludes the upper bound.

Comment: Excellent - it works for me! Thank you guys for always being nice to newbies :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your loop.
You're assigning a new value for freq each time, overwriting the old value of freq. What you are trying to do in the last line is to access an element of a list, but it is not a list (it is an int).
If you want to be freq a list of all frequencies, change your line in the loop to:

```
freq.append(k[n]*samplerate/N)
```

Edit: Maybe I don't understand your problem correctly, though, then please tell us what the result shall look like.

Comment: Thank you so much! Thank you guys for always being nice to newbies :)

Comment: For this approach, remember to set `freq = []` before the loop to avoid `NameError`